# Why does the `datatype: json` break this function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why does specifying `datatype: json` break this AJAX call?

I've looked at other posts, but they seem to be JSON formatting related issues.

- the JSON data is contained in thisOneEvaluation
- The `data:`parameter is valid JSON - confirmed on JSONlint
- commenting out the dataType call makes it work just fine

Here's the .js code:

```
var thisOneEvaluation = JSON.stringify(survey.data);
//console.log("The results are:" + thisOneEvaluation);
// {"question2":"Z","question1":"5","question3":"5"}

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/getRequest",  
        headers: {
                  'CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        dataType : "json",    // <<<< This is the culprit.. but why?
        data: thisOneEvaluation,

        })
```

Comment: `dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server, it breaks probably because the server isn't sending back a valid `json` , see : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I thought dataType was what I SENT to the server?

Comment: @Maxcot No. As stated in the docs: _“`dataType`: The type of data that **you’re expecting back from the server**. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.”_